# Linq to file system to get last created file in each sub folders

Tags: c#, linq, filesystems

I have a folder/directory that contains some sub directories.

Only those sub folders contain files.
I have to get the full path of last created files in each sub folder.

Only the last created file in each sub folder is needed.

How can I do this? How can I use linq to files stem for this

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far? This sounds like a simple thing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SomeFolder");

var recentFiles = di.GetDirectories()
                    .Select(x=>x.EnumerateFiles()
                                .OrderByDescending(f=> f.CreationTimeUtc)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
                    .Where(x=> x!=null)
                    .Select(x=>x.FullName)
                    .ToList();
```

One thing to be mindful of is the permissions you need to traverse some protected directories, this shouldn't be a problem for most cases though.

Comment: Modified this for getting directies by creation order. Useful!